# How do I make "node ." work?

Tags: node.js, default

I've run `node .` in various NodeJS apps in the past, and it seems to know to run `index.js`, `server.js`, etc.  Is there a `package.json` setting (or something similar) that I can configure so that NodeJS knows which file should run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

npm does have a one configuration for that:

```
"main": "app.js"
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  Will mark as the correct answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me. :)